# Detecting the launch of a application

Tags: c#, c++, windows

How do I detect with C# on Windows the moment when an external application is being launched?

I tried the FilesystemWatcher which doesn't work because the file is not really changing. Also having a timer constantly check all the open processes might be a bit over kill. Is there any other way to do this? If not in C# is it possible to do so in C++ (if so please give me an example).

The reason I want to do this is for logging purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) and [WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)

```
class WMIEvent {
    public static void Main() {
        WMIEvent we = new WMIEvent();
        ManagementEventWatcher w= null;
        WqlEventQuery q;
        try {
            q = new WqlEventQuery();
            q.EventClassName = "Win32_ProcessStartTrace";
            w = new ManagementEventWatcher(q);
            w.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(we.ProcessStartEventArrived);
            w.Start();
            Console.ReadLine(); // block main thread for test purposes
        }
        finally {
            w.Stop();
        }
 }

    public void ProcessStartEventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {    
        foreach(PropertyData pd in e.NewEvent.Properties) {
            Console.WriteLine("\n============================= =========");
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",pd.Name, pd.Type, pd.Value);
        }
  }
```

Comment: @stalkerh How did you make this work? Various types, like the MangementEventWatcher, doesn't exist in System.Management or System.Mangement.Instrumentation. Where do I find them? Did I miss something?

Comment: Nevermind. Had to add a reference to System.Management dll as well. Not just add `using System.Management;`... *sigh* :p

Comment: Yeah i noticed that and fixed without posting here

Comment: I'm getting an error: "Unhandled Exception: System.Management.ManagementException: Access denied"

Comment: You need to run it as administrator or else you get that Access denied exception.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this is only .NET Framework 4.7.2