# How to know an application launch in windows?

Tags: c#, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting the launch of a application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649900/detecting-the-launch-of-a-application)

Can I register a listener and get notification when an application launch?

I know that in Mac NSWorkSpace can do it, how about windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a Forever loop
while(true)
{
  if(Process.GetProcessesByName("TheSoftwareYouNeed").Length > 0)
   Notify();//Here you can call a method which handles with notyfind
}